# iOS: Create copy of UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

It is possible, to create an exact object copy of a `UINavigationController`?  I have seen examples of copying objects using `copyWithZone:`, but I am confused as to how I would use this to copy my `UINavigationController`.

Any help?

Comment: This sounds like a disaster waiting to happen. Too many conflicts with the data that view controllers represent, endless nights pulling your hair out trying to duplicate the state of all the view controllers, and so on. If you need to show the same navigation controller in multiple tabs or something, I'd just move its `view` around as needed.

Answer (score 1):

`UINavigationController` doesn't conform to the `NSCopying` protocol, so you can't use `copyWithZone:` or `copy` on it.

If you are looking to have a customised `UINavigationController` that you can use throughout the app then you should subclass it and then create a new instance of that subclass every time you need a new one, such as when you create a new modal view controller.

EDIT: If you want to keep the view controllers from a previous navigation controller then you can do something like this (use subclassed navigation controller if needed):

```
UINavigationController *newNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[newNavigationController setViewControllers:oldNavigationController.viewControllers animated:NO];
```

This will do a shallow copy of the viewControllers, i.e. you will have references to the original navigation controller's view controllers, not copies. If you want to do a deep copy on the view controllers then that will be far more complicated and will require specific copying code for each view controller. (See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy) for more info).

Comment: You missed the point. I want to create a copy, not a new instance of the class.  It needs to have all of the viewControllers that the original had.

Comment: Again, you shouldn't be doing this through a `copy` command. I'll edit the answer to show how to do this.

Comment: By the way, personally I wouldn't advise using the above code to do a shallow copy of the view controllers. This is one of those things that hard because the framework is being used it ways it shouldn't. Are they ways of doing what you want without copying the navigation controller?

Comment: Let me explain. Say I have navigated 5 levels deep in my `UINavigationController`. At that point, I select 3 cells, and invoke my "move" method. This brings up a `modalViewController` so that the user can move those cells elsewhere in the view stack. THIS is the reason I want to copy the first `UINavigationController`, because I want the modal to start at level 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a category (or a subclass), make the category NSCoding compliant, and add the necessary encoding and decoding functions. You then need to determine what properties you want to encode - the types of view controllers it currently has in its array, and perhaps you'll need to make those objects be NSCoding compliant. You can see that this is not going to be a trivial thing to do, but its not impossible. You may find the solution to your problem is best done using some other techniques.

EDIT: If you want to "duplicate" it, what you really need to know is what viewControllers are in the array. So suppose you want to replicate "state", which in some sense is the same as the original answer but less rigorous. Add a category or method to each object and ask to to give you current state as a dictionary. For the navigationController, that might be just the classes of the objects currently on the stack.

For each of these objects on the stack, you get them to give you a dictionary of their state. By state, its means what text is in UITextFields, views etc, anything that that object would need to go from a startup condition and get back to where it is now.

You package this all up - the nav dictionary and array of the state ones. You can save this as a plist. When you want to construct where you were later, the nav controller can tell what objects to create by knowing their class, then as each one is created it can be sent its dictionary and told "get back to where you were". Once done, then push another controller on the stack.

Comment: You mention other techniques, what might these be?